# Exclude no comma case in regex

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

I have created this RE: `^[ ]{0,1}[^\s]` to match:

```
1 min
1 min, 2 min, 3 min
```

but I don't know how to exclude this particular case: `1 min 2 min 3 min`.

Or I would like the strings to be only comma separated?

Comment: So for the last case, you'd like to match "1min" "2 min" and "3 min"?

Comment: I like to match that and the comma separated as well.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
^\d+ min(?:, \d+ min)*$
```

**Explanation:**

```
^               : beginning of string
\d+ min         : 1 or more digits, a space then min
(?:             : start non capture group
  , \d+ min     : a comma, a space, 1 or more digits, a space then min
)*              : end group, may appear 0 or more times
$               : end of string
```

Comment: It stil matches "1 min 2 min"

Comment: There should be a space after the comma. Like this: "1 min, 2 min, 3 min"

Comment: Also I am using Python notations.

Comment: @ot123: There is a space after the comma in my regex. It works with Python. Add the raw notation: `r'^\d+ min(?:, \d+ min)*$'`

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this would work for you:

```
r'(((,)?\s?\d+\s+min)+)'
```

Comment: This doesn't match `1 min`

Comment: Now it matches `,1  min` or `1 min2 min 3       min`